# How to map root context to webapp context in embedded tomcat using spring boot

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, reverse-proxy

Some background on my problem is that we have had a tomcat application running under "/context" in standalone tomcat. We have apache sitting in front of this encrypting the traffic and mapping requests for "/" to "/context" on the tomcat server. 
 I have just reworked the tomcat application to run in spring boot. What we are doing is using spring boot to build an executable war file that contains our original war. When we execute the new war file, its main method will create an embedded tomcat instance and deploy our original war file on the original context. 
 We are using code that works with the TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory to do this.

My question is what is the easiest way to redirect requests to "/" to "/context" in this new setup? I have tried making a "ROOT" folder in the unpack directory but I can't get embedded tomcat to serve any files out of there. 
There is no more apache and no more standalone tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I solved my own problem. All I had to do was add a @RequestMapping that took "/" to the context path I wanted everything to go to. 
 I didn't know how to do this because we haven't been using spring-boot for much, we are just deploying our legacy war in it and I wasn't familiar with how to work the the web features.